# Get website content after JavaScript loading with python

Tags: javascript, python

I've got issue with getting an content:

```
with dryscrape.Session() as c:
    PASSWORD = '<PASS>'
    USERNAME = '<EMAIL>'
    URL = 'https://my.pingdom.com/'
    c.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c.get(URL).text, "lxml")
    csrf = soup.select_one("input[name=__csrf_magic]")["value"]
    login_data = {
        "email" : USERNAME,
        "password" : PASSWORD,
        "__csrf_magic" : csrf,}
r = c.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'})
url = 'https://my.pingdom.com/newchecks/rums?ignoreActive=1'
r = c.get(url).text
print r
```

And after login in browser i've got value of Load Time in source code, but when i'm using this scipt there is only an {{loadtime}} tag from `x-handlebars-template`.
Any ideas how I can get it? This is server script so any selenium type of tips doesn't go in here. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/2741678

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I need to login into webpage and after that scrap page.